# Flask CSRF Protection setting invalid Set-Cookie on response headers

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a product catalog using Flask and Firebase Authentication. I'm following their docs on how to set up both client and server using their pre-built UI and Session Cookies as stated here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

<strike>GET requests work fine, the server verifies the session cookie on each request and sends content accordingly. But when I do a POST request (submitting a form to create a new item, for example) the server is unable to parse the cookie.</strike>

I verified using the Chrome Dev Tools that the session cookie sent to the server on both GET and POST requests are the same. Tried several things I've found googling about similar problems but anything worked. I also tried to find a similar question here but I haven't found any.

EDIT: After a few hours looking again at the problem, I've seen that the cookies are NOT the same on the GET and POST request. I've looked at the requests with the Chrome Dev Tools and I've seen that the GET response returns a Set-Cookie header with an invalid cookie (what makes the POST request to have an invalid cookie and redirect again to the login page).

This only happens on pages where login is required (and redirects to login page if you are not logged in), but still I can't find why Flask is sending a Set-Cookie header with an invalid cookie.

EDIT2: After a few more hours, I've found out that removing the CSRF hidden input from the form on those pages fix the cookie problem (the GET request doesn't make a Set-Cookie), so it has to be related with the CSRF thing but I don't know how. There is any special behavior on session cookies when using CSRF that I'm not taking into account?

"New Item" template:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    New item
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='form.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{{ url_for('newItem') }}" method = 'post'>
    <h1>Create a new item</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type='text' size='30' name='name' placeholder="Name" required>
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea rows='4' name='description' placeholder="Description" required></textarea>
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type='text' size='30' name='price' placeholder="Price" required>
    <label>Image URI</label>
    <input type='text' size='30' name='image' placeholder="https://example.com/image.png" required>
    <label>Category</label>
    <select name='category' required>
        {% for c in categories %}
        <option value="{{ c.id }}">{{ c.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Create'>
    <a href="{{ url_for('categories') }}">Cancel</a>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

"Login Required" decorator:

```py
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        session_cookie = request.cookies.get('session')
        # Verify the session cookie. In this case an additional check is added to detect
        # if the user's Firebase session was revoked, user deleted/disabled, etc.
        try:
            decoded_claims = auth.verify_session_cookie(session_cookie, check_revoked=True)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError as e:
            # Session cookie is unavailable or invalid. Force user to login.
            print(e)
            return redirect(url_for('login', mode="select", signInSuccessUrl=request.url))
        except auth.AuthError as e:
            # Session revoked. Force user to login.
            print(e)
            return redirect(url_for('login', mode="select", signInSuccessUrl=request.url))
    return decorated_function
```

"Items" endpoint (works as expected):

```py
@app.route('/items/<int:item_id>/')
def item(item_id):
    session = DBSession()
    item = session.query(Item).get(item_id)

    session_cookie = flask.request.cookies.get('session')
    # Verify the session cookie. In this case an additional check is added to detect
    # if the user's Firebase session was revoked, user deleted/disabled, etc.
    try:
        auth.verify_session_cookie(session_cookie, check_revoked=True)
        return render_template('item.html', item=item, logged=True)
    except ValueError as e:
        # Session cookie is unavailable or invalid. Force user to login.
        print(e)
        return render_template('item.html', item=item, logged=False)
    except auth.AuthError as e:
        # Session revoked. Force user to login.
        print(e)
        return render_template('item.html', item=item, logged=False)
```

"New Item" endpoint (returns a Set-Cookie header with an invalid cookie to GET requests):

```py
@app.route('/items/new/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def newItem():
    session_cookie = flask.request.cookies.get('session')
    decoded_claims = auth.verify_session_cookie(session_cookie, check_revoked=True)

    session = DBSession()
    categories = session.query(Category).all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('new_item.html', categories=categories, logged=True)
    else:
        # SOME LOGIC HERE
        # [...]
        return redirect(url_for('item', item_id = newItem.id))
```

The error I get on the POST request is the following:

```
Value Error
Can't parse segment: \���
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem I changed the cookie name from 'session' to any other name. I don't know why Flask keeps sending Set-Cookie headers for the 'session' cookie, so if anyone knows why please comment it out.

Comment: Flask sends a Set-Cookie with the session cookie with most responses in order to keep it alive by pushing the expiry date to 30 days from now. It's an alternative strategy to setting a cookie with a very long lifespan.

Comment: Oh this was so hard to debug, thank you so very much!