# firebase python sdk auth.verify_session_cookie() only seems to work once?

Tags: python, flask, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am working on a login workflow in Flask using the Firebase SDK. The flow goes Login then navigate to a secure page. On the secured page we utilize `auth.verify_session_cookie()` to verify if the user is legitimate.
With the code below, the login is successful. I can then navigate to the protected page, and in my print statements I can see my `decoded_claims` verify the cookie. However, when I go to a second protected page, it fails and I get an `auth.InvalidSessionCookieError`. I don't think this is timeout related as I can jump between pages quickly and always the second load dies on the error and redirects me to login again.

How I am initializing the Firebase app:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("keys/s..........c.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

My login function (which seems to be working):

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method =="POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        apikey = "AIza..............."
        details={
            'email': form.email.data,
            'password': form.password.data,
            'returnSecureToken': True}
        r=requests.post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key={}'.format(apikey),data=details)
        if 'idToken' in r.json().keys():
            id_token = r.json()['idToken']
            expires_in = timedelta(days=5)
            try:
                session_cookie = auth.create_session_cookie(id_token, expires_in=expires_in)
                response = make_response(redirect('/index'))
                expires = datetime.now() + expires_in
                response.set_cookie('session', session_cookie, expires=expires, httponly=True, secure=True)
                return response
            except:
                if 'error' in r.json().keys():
                    error_message = r.json()['error']['message']
                    flash(error_message)
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template("login.html",
                            form = form)
```

I am then using a decorator function to check the credentials (this seems to work once):

```
def authentication_required(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def check_auth_status(*args, **kwargs):
        session_cookie = request.cookies.get('session')
        if not session_cookie:
            flash("Login required to view the requested page.")
            return redirect('/login')
        try:
            decoded_claims = auth.verify_session_cookie(session_cookie, check_revoked=True)
            print(decoded_claims)
            if decoded_claims:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except auth.InvalidSessionCookieError:
            flash("Please login to view the requested page.")
            return redirect('/login')
    return check_auth_status
```

And finally I call a route:

```
@app.route('/faq')
@authentication_required
def faq():
    return render_template('faq.html')
```

I suspect that by calling `auth.verify_session_cookie()` I am invalidating the id_token or I need to work with a refresh_token, but I am stuck at present. If it makes any difference I am running on localhost.

Here are the pages I have been looking at for documentation:
[Firebase Manage Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies)

[Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#verify_session_cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Per this post: [Flask CSRF Protection setting invalid Set-Cookie on response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045065/flask-csrf-protection-setting-invalid-set-cookie-on-response-headers)

The solution is pretty easy... The csrf from the forms overwrites the 'session' variable, so any name other than 'session' will work... E.g., 'xsession'.